# Where to find a database of all the camera models

Tags: equipment-recommendation, body, camera

I am looking for a list of all models of digital cameras that have been released on the market since around 2005.
Ideally it would specify basic specs such as the sensor resolution and sensor type.

Surely it must exist somewhere?

Comment: It probably doesn't... You can probably find a list covering at least the major manufacturers (Canon, Nikon, Sony, etc...), but one that universally covers all manufacturers is unlikely...

Comment: Hi and welcome to Photo.SE! This is not a "regular" forum, so please take a moment to take the [tour]. It'll probably help you get more out of this website in the future.
I also doubt that there is a complete list, but perhaps we can come up with a different solution to your actual problem. **Why** do you need a list with specs? Feel free to edit your question to include the reason.

Answer (score 1):

DPReview has a product database that includes cameras.  I doubt they have *every* camera on there, but they definitely have a lot of them.

The [product database](https://www.dpreview.com/products/cameras/all?view=list) has a few specs on the main page which sound like they are in line with what you're looking for: sensor size and resolution are shown for most cameras.
They also have a [product timeline](https://www.dpreview.com/products/timeline?year=all&brand=&category=cameras), which seems to be more geared toward *announcements* than the actual cameras, but it may be useful to you.

Comment: Thank you, that is a very good start.

Comment: https://www.neocamera.com/ Is fairly extensive as well